# Run npm 32-bit on linux 64-bit system?

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, npm

So I download this: `https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-win-x86.zip`

Unzip it. Then install wine 32-bit:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y wine32
```

I get this error message:

```
wine ./node/npm --version
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\srv\node\npm..
```

The `node.exe` works though:

```
wine node/node.exe --version
v10.16.3

ls -la node/
total 21544
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Aug 15 18:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Sep 19 09:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    53390 Aug 15 18:19 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    70122 Aug 15 18:19 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    27446 Aug 15 18:19 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21845656 Aug 15 18:54 node.exe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    10630 May 24  2018 node_etw_provider.man
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Aug 15 18:54 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     4974 Aug 15 18:19 node_perfctr_provider.man
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      702 May 24  2018 nodevars.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      867 Aug 15 18:19 npm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      483 May 24  2018 npm.cmd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      922 May 26  2018 npx
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      539 May 26  2018 npx.cmd
```

As you can see npm is not an exe. How does one run the 32-bit npm on a 64-bit linux system via wine 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can  be able to clone the repo into `node_modules` yourself and compile it manually using

```
node-gyp clean configure build --verbose --target_arch=ia32
```

inside the directory where you cloned the repo.